# Mute Tag Not Working - Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In the html file:

```
<video preload="metadata" muted="true" controls playsinline webkit-playsinline loop>
```

The video does not pick up the muted tag and plays with sound instead in both the browser and on the device.

If I reference the video and set the volume through the .ts

```
    el.volume = 0;
```

The mute works on the browser but still does not work on the device.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `=true` after `muted`. It should just work on it's own.

You could also try
`document.getElementById("myVideo").muted = true;`

Comment: Wow, that was easy enough. The muted = true seemed to do the trick. Thank you!